# Best way of handling pan gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to handle transitions between two instances of the same view controller class, using pan gestures.

I've read almost every transitions can be handled by segues, but is it the same when using pan gestures?

Segues don't seem to be a good fit for this kind of transitions.

For the moment, I have a master view controller which instantiates to sub view controllers. The gesture related code resides in the master view controller.

It works well, but I believe there has to be a solution where all the controller management stuff is done in the storyboard.

What is the best place in my code to handle this kind of transitions?

Comment: I recommend you check out the [WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=218), specifically session 218, "Custom Transitions Using View Controllers."

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a really great article on the way to implement custom transitions with iOS 7, whether they're interactive or not: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions-more

It comes with a very detailed demo.

Animations should be classes implementing the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning or UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning protocols.

The code using the gesture recognizer can reside in those classes.

The animation can then be returned in the following methods of your navigation controller delegate:

- navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:
- navigationController:interactionControllerForAnimationController:

This way I can plug the animation to whatever controller I want to.

I hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like what you want is a UIPageViewController set up to scroll instead of page curl (That's a settable property) A page view controller would do all the work for you.

There is a sample app in the Xcode docs called PhotoScroller that shows how to set this up. It does lots of other stuff too, (pinch to zoom and image tiling) but you can ignore that.

If you can't get a UIPageViewController to give you the transition you want then you might need to build your own custom parent view controller class. Embedding a single child using a container VC and an embed segue is trivial. I haven't tried to embed multiple children in the same container yet. using embed segues yet. I've done transitions between child VCs using the "manual" parent/child VC calls that were added in iOS 5

Comment: Thanks Duncan. Is it possible to customize the transition of an UIPageViewController?
I want to do a very specific kind of transition, where the presented view controller slides on top of the next view controller.

Comment: I don't know. It might not be.